# Magento 2 ajax on checkout

Tags: magento2, ajax

On the checkout/#shipping page there is NEXT button. Where in code is ajax fired for that button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Checkout, js are configure through xml. So open

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml
```

look

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping</item>
```

line. So js file should be

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

Open it and look following method '**setShippingInformation**'. This method is responsible for next button in checkout shipping.

**NB:** Don't forget to overwrite/extend this method.(Don't modify core code)